# Spinner won't get displayed on running the application

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm trying to work with spinner. I have other views along with the spinner. All other views are displayed and work fine except spinner. Upon execution spinner is not visible at all. It is however displayed in design mode but not upon execution.

My XML is as below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context="com.example.kc.sample.HomePage">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/fontStyle"
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_registerName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:textColor="#274A72"
                    android:id="@+id/editRegisterName"
                    android:hint="@string/Name"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLength="64"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/fontStyle"
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_registerDOB"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:textColor="#274A72"
                    android:id="@+id/editRegisterDOB"
                    android:hint="@string/DOB"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLength="64"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stretchColumns="*"
                android:shrinkColumns="*">
                <TableRow>
                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        style="@style/fontStyle"
                        android:id="@+id/input_layout_GenderMale"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1">
                        <RadioButton
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:textSize="15dp"
                            android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                            android:textColor="#274A72"
                            android:id="@+id/radioGenderMale"
                            android:text="@string/Male"
                            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
                            android:onClick="checkMaleMethod"
                        />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        style="@style/fontStyle"
                        android:id="@+id/input_layout_GenderFemale"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1">
                        <RadioButton
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:textSize="15dp"
                            android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                            android:textColor="#274A72"
                            android:id="@+id/radioGenderFemale"
                            android:text="@string/Female"
                            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
                            android:onClick="checkFemaleMethod"
                        />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/fontStyle"
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_registerEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:textColor="#274A72"
                    android:id="@+id/editRegisterEmail"
                    android:hint="@string/email"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLength="64"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/fontStyle"
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_registerMobile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/editRegisterPhone"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:textColor="#274A72"
                    android:hint="@string/Phone"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLength="10"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stretchColumns="*"
                android:shrinkColumns="*">
                <TableRow>
                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        style="@style/fontStyle"
                        android:id="@+id/input_layout_statusSingle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1">
                        <RadioButton
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:textSize="15dp"
                            android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                            android:textColor="#274A72"
                            android:id="@+id/radioStatusSingle"
                            android:text="@string/Single"
                            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
                            android:onClick="checkStatusSingleMethod"
                            />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        style="@style/fontStyle"
                        android:id="@+id/input_layout_statusMarried"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1">
                        <RadioButton
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:textSize="15dp"
                            android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                            android:textColor="#274A72"
                            android:id="@+id/radioStatusMarried"
                            android:text="@string/Married"
                            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
                            android:onClick="checkStatusMarriedMethod"
                            />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:prompt="@string/spinner_title"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtErrorMessage"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textColor="#ff0000"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

My corresponding java code is as below:

```
public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener {

    private EditText editName, editDateofBirth, editMail, editMobileNumber, editDate;
    private RadioButton radioMale, radioFemale, radioStatusSingle, radioStatusMarried;
    private Button btnPrevious, btnNext;
    Dialog result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

        //Few other view declaration here

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("One");
        list.add("Two");
        list.add("Three");
        list.add("Four");

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);           dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        String item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
        Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
```

The same Spinner code if written as a separate individual project works fine and as expected but including the same in the above code snippet won't display spinner upon execution. Can anyone guide me how to make it work? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Fill property is deprecated, use:

```
<Spinner
   android:id="@+id/spinner"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:prompt="@string/spinner_title"
            />
```